# Can New Horizons be turned into an orbiter for the Pluto system?

Tags: gravity-assist, new-horizons, pluto

If the New Horizons team [doesn't find](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/05/21/pluto-probe-new-horizons-crisis_n_5364138.html) a KBO target for the probe, can they turn it into an orbiter for the Pluto system? I know entering orbit right now  would be impossible, but would it be possible to achieve this by making a first fly by, turning back and getting some help from [Saturn or Jupiter](http://www.solarsystemscope.com/) in the future years?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78U0_XcFP_I) of New Horizon's trajectory. After it flies by Pluto, it's not coming back. It's leaving the solar system on a hyperbolic trajectory.

Edit:
If the hyperbolic periapsis was moved to within 10 km of Pluto's surface, the turning angle would be increased to about .4 degrees. Not much of a path change, not sufficient to send it back towards one of the gas giants.

Comment: my question was if this trajectory can still be modified to make a closer approach to Pluto, make a gravity slingshot to propel it back to Jupiter or Saturn in order to make a come back in a few years as an orbiter for Pluto

Comment: If the hyperbolic periapsis was moved to within 10 km of Pluto's surface, the turning angle would be increased to about .4 degrees. Not much of a path change, not sufficient to send it back towards one of the gas giants.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that New Horizons does not have sufficient reactive control energy to establish an orbit about Pluto.

Comment: Hi Willy and welcome to the Space stack exchange. You're quite right with your answer, but if possible try and provide a reference/ calculation to support your answers!