# Would it have been possible to instead keep New Horizons with Pluto?

Tags: probe, new-horizons, pluto

I understand that New Horizons has [further objectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons#Future_mission_objectives) after Pluto, but they seem to be very iffy, whether they will produce anything valuable.  [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/can-new-horizons-be-turned-into-an-orbiter-for-the-pluto-system) is related, but I'm more interested in *why*.

During the design of the mission, was the reason to leave Pluto due to:

- Concrete and specific objectives to continue outward,
- Previous lack of know-how to put New Horizons into close orbit of Pluto, or
- Is the function and nature of New Horizons not compatible with close-up imagery, data collection and communication with Earth?

**Why aren't we staying with Pluto, and gathering more information?**  Given that it's possible nothing will be found of interest in the Kuiper Belt.

Comment: A mission to orbit Pluto would have been massively more expensive. See this related question: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9851/requirements-to-orbit-pluto

Comment: New Horizons is going really fast.  In order to get into orbit, it would need to go much much slower.  Slowing down requires energy, and producing that energy would require a lot of fuel which the probe does not have enough of.